# Proof using logic consequence. Is this correct?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, first-order-logic

Try to proof this using the definition of logic consequence.

$\forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta), \forall x \alpha \models \forall x \beta$

Let's say that: $\Gamma = \alpha \rightarrow \beta$, by definition of logic consequence: for all interpretation $\mathfrak{I}\models\Gamma$ must then  $\mathfrak{I}\models\forall x \beta$.

Suppose any interpretation $\mathfrak{I}$ such that $\mathfrak{I}\models\Gamma$. 
With this i have that $\mathfrak{I}$ satisfy this two cases:

1) $\mathfrak{I}\models\forall x(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$

By definition of relation of satisfaction of "$\forall$":

for all a $\in$ A, $\mathfrak{I}[a/x]\models(\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$

By definition of relation of satisfaction of "$\rightarrow$":

for all a $\in$ A, if $\mathfrak{I}[a/x]\models\alpha$ then $\mathfrak{I}[a/x]\models\beta$

2) $\mathfrak{I}\models\forall x \alpha$.

By definition of relation of satisfaction of "$\forall$":

for all a $\in$ A, $\mathfrak{I}[a/x]\models\alpha$

So, since there is a interpretation that satisfy 1) and this interpretation also satisfy 2). By Modus Ponens(1 and 2) we have:

for all a $\in$ A, $\mathfrak{I}[a/x]\models \beta$.

By definition of relation of satisfaction of "$\forall$" we have:

$\mathfrak{I}\models\forall x \beta$.

This proof is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your proof looks correct.